# How to make a border-radius for Skeleton by react-loading-skeleton?

Tags: reactjs, react-loading-skeleton

I need to create Skeleton using the react-loading-skeleton library. One item should have border radius like at the picture below.

[image]

Do you know how to make it?

My lib version:
`"react-loading-skeleton": "1.2.0"` (low possibility of upgrade)

I tried to solve it in this way, but it doesn't work :(

```
<Skeleton
    width={127}
    borderRadius={12.5}
/>
```

Comment: Add a wrapper to your Skeleton like in the documentation : https://github.com/dvtng/react-loading-skeleton#custom-wrapper

Use css border-radius and maybe overflow hidden if necessary.

Comment: I tried, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper like this :

```
.rounded-skeleton {
  border-radius: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

JSX:

```
  <div className="rounded-skeleton">
    <Skeleton />
  </div>
```

[CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-architecture-dxs8v?file=/src/App.js)